# Access reference in combination with RefLibPaths crashes access on exit

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm having the following issue. I've got a .mde that needs to use another .mde for some functions. That referenced .mde has to be on a unique location for every user. I thought I could drop it on our P:\ drive (which exists for every user but leads to a different folder). The only issue I got there access saves the UNC path and which gets translated to \\[server]\[user]\mylib.mde instead of P:\mylib.mde

So I thought I would use this guide:
http://smsconsulting.spb.ru/shamil_s/topics/testrefs.htm
When I use this it works. Except that I can't close Access without crashing Access.

Some more detailed information about our environment. We're running on Win7 with office 2010 except for Access, which is Access 2003.

Anyone got an idea why this does not work?

EDIT: After some extra testing I've noticed that I Access does not crash when the reference .mde is located on my local hard drive, it only crashes when it's on a network drive.

Comment: Does each user have their own copy of mde #1 on their desktop? Because that is the correct way to use an mde

Comment: Yes, each user gets a copy of the first .mde. However they also need their own copy of the reference .mde and I can't find way a way to reference the first .mde to a unique 2nd .mde

Comment: Why do the users need their own copy of a second mde? It seems to me that the only reason would be to write to that copy, which suggests that it should not be included as a reference, only as a link. I wonder if a lateral approach would be suggested by someone if you posted more details?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested with adding to an an mde only to an mdb, but it may be worth trying this:

```
Dim ref As Reference

On Error Resume Next
References.AddFromFile "C:\docs\Some.mde"

''Just checking
For Each ref In References
    s = s & vbCrLf & "Name: " & ref.Name
Next
```

Comment: Nope that didn't work for an .mde. Only seems to work for a .mdb